# Exporting env variables persistantly

Tags: environment-variables

I'm trying to figure out how to create persistant environment variables for my "root" user. I've tried running this in command line:

```
export ETSY_CONSUMER_SECRET='xxx'
export ETSY_CONSUMER_KEY='xxx'
```

If I then type:

```
echo $ETSY_CONSUMER_SECRET
```

I correctly get the value back. BUT as soon as I close the terminal and reload it, the variable is gone.

I then read you should add it to your **/root/.bashrc** file to make it persistant. So I added this there:

```
export ETSY_CONSUMER_KEY='xxx'
export ETSY_CONSUMER_SECRET='xxx'
```

reloaded the SSH connection, but I get nothing when doing:

echo $ETSY_CONSUMER_SECRET

I even tried just doing:

```
ETSY_CONSUMER_KEY='xxx'
ETSY_CONSUMER_SECRET='xxx'
```

But the same problem.

What am I missing?

Comment: Puth those in the `/etc/environment` file without the `export` keyword ythe it will be persistent

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen would that mean any other user can access them though? (they are API keys, so I don't want anyone else to be able to see them outside of the users I allow)

Comment: Ok that's true other users will access them. Now did you creat a seperate root user or the root user here is the one in the sudo group?

Comment: Thanks. This is just the standard root user (comes with the VestaCP setup). I guess its the sudo root as well. How would I check?

Comment: That user would have a passwd set for it so you could do a `su root` to switch to that account or do `cat /etc/passwd | grep root` and if you see an account then it's there!

Comment: cat /etc/passwd | grep root
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86166/discussion-between-george-udosen-and-andrew-newby).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put them in the `/etc/environment` like so:

```
ETSY_CONSUMER_SECRET='xxx'
ETSY_CONSUMER_KEY='xxx'
```

Note theat the `export` keyword isn't added in this case. Now you should be able to use them whenever.